# How to start genetic algorithms (MATLAB)

Tags: algorithm, matlab, genetic-algorithm

This might sound like a very stupid question, but I have spent the last hours trying to go through online tutorials about genetic algorithms and I left with more questions as before.

I have a robot that shall move according to its current situation, read: the robot "knows" about its surroundings and has to operate according to the gene linked to that situation.
In my case I have 4 different actions the robot can take and two kinds of obstacles it can detect (obstacles it can not cross like a wall and obstacles it can cross, like a wire on the ground or whatever).

Coming to the problem:
Do you normally set up a huge Operation-Matrix with all permutations (I tried the perm(v) function, but it does not include a varying number of the same type) and do you check in each time step for the situation of the robot and then go through the Op-matrix to determine the ID of the situation and get the according ID in the Chromosome to execute the corresponding 1-4 action?

My problem with almost all resources I found is: I can totally understand, how theory is working, but I have no clue on how to start this thing in MATLAB, and the method I described above seems to be very inefficient.

If anyone has any thoughts to share I would appreciate this.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you simulating the robot or is it a real life robot? What exactly are you trying to optimize? If it's a real life robot, have you thought of combining neural networks and genetic algorithms?

Comment: Hi! No we are simulating that robot (it is a Mathematical Masters program). So this is on a very basic level only, from the view of CS I guess ^^. That robot should only move in a very simple 2D environment (read: grid).